# How to set cell size by each column wise using jspdf?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, jspdf

I have so many `HTML` tables in my application, each table has different no of columns. I wrote the same script code for all pages so I need to set cell size on the basis of table id. I can get table Id how any but cant looping column wise..

reached till here :

```
    $.each(table1, function (i, row) {

            rowCount++;
            $.each(row, function (j, cellContent) {

                if (rowCount == 1) {

                    doc.margins = 1;
                    doc.setFont("helvetica");
                    doc.setFontType("bold");
                    doc.setFontSize(11);

//trying by this but cant get each cell wise.
                    for (var k = 0; k <= row[j].length; k++) {
                        if (TblId == 'Tbl_AddUser' && k==0) {
                            cellWidth = 20;
                        }
                        else if (TblId == 'Tbl_AddUser' && k == 3) {
                            cellWidth = 40;
                        }
                        doc.cell(leftMargin, topMargin, cellWidth, headerRowHeight, cellContent, i);
                    }

                }
         })

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

just write the below code inside of first each loop.

```
if (table.replace('#', '') == 'sample_2') {
            for (var k = 0; k < ActualTbl.rows[rowCount].cells.length; k++) {
                cellWidth = 30;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

The correct way to add table-specific settings would be to use css classes.
In your case, you can have css rules based on table IDs.

```css
table#table1 tr td {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table#table2 tr td {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id='table1'>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell in table-1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id='table2'>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell in table-2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```